# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.I dont want to use dispatcher

Tags: wpf, synchronization, dispatcher

in wpf,I have a listbox control  and two buttons.I want to be able to use the second button when i clicked the first button till add numbers has not fineshed his work.I use dispatcher.begininvoke but this adds the work on main thread.How to i synchronize this threads?I want to be able to use second button, move the window or using other ui elements when addnumbers processing..

```
    void AddNumbers()
    {

                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(i);
                }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AddNumbers));
        thr.Start();


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
    }
```

Comment: You can't. It's not the loop that takes time, it's the `Add` call. What you can do is try wrapping the method in `listBox1.BeginUpdate()` and `listBox1.EndUpdate()` to stop it from painting in between, though.

Comment: This will require the dispatcher, or a threadsafe `observablecollection` with databinding. There is nothing wrong with using the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Only the main (UI) thread can access a UI control.  And why do you need 1 million items in a Listbox?   Listbox supports virtualization.  Use a BackgroundWorker (or thread) to create the List and then on the RunWorkerCompleted is when you bind the List to the UI ListBox.     As far as synch you just enable / disable when you start BackgroundWorker and the enable / disapble on the callback.  Again why do you need 1 million items in a ListBox?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: adding 1 million items is a just a long call.Actually i wanted to know that i could use illegal cross thread calls then i handle thread synchronizing on ui elements.thanks by the way...

Comment: OK then a comment simulate long operation would helped as I saw it as a rendering issue.  I would still consider Background and Disable Enable.  I agree with the comment from Tyrsius.